# Lumen file cache driver

Tags: laravel, caching, lumen

I'm in Lumen, inside a Controller, and I would like to cache a computation's result in a simple and easy way, without using database or external services, so I was looking for save the cache in the filesystem. In [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache#configuration) there is cited the `file` driver:

> By default, Laravel is configured to use the file cache driver, which
>   stores the serialized, cached objects in the filesystem.

And I can see it, configured as *Default Cache Store*, inside `config/cache.php`.

In [Lumen's documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/cache) i can't see anything about the file driver and I find nothing like the file `cache.php` inside Lumen installation.

So my question is if I can use the file cache driver in Lumen (by setting `CACHE_DRIVER=file`) or if it is discouraged, not supported, not implemented or something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Lumen in `.env.example` you have by default:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
```

So all you need is to  change filename from `.env.example` to `.env` and set

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
```

If you read [Caching in Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/cache#cache-usage) you'll see in example:

```
$value = Cache::store('file')->get('foo');
```

so `file` driver is supported by Lumen.

If you also read [Lumen Configuration](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation#configuration) you can read here that you can copy configuration files you need (in case you need them) and load them manually. You can see default Luman cache config file here: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.1/config/cache.php